# How to fix a flaky Capybara test for the Devise password reset flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, capybara, minitest

I have a flaky system test in Rails that I can't seem to fix. Each time this test initially started failing I kept adding a few seconds to capybara's `using_wait_time` method and the test would pass for a while. Usually this test passes in isolation and then fails when I run my entire test suite. Then I bump up the wait time and it will pass for a while when running the entire test suite until I change something else in my app that for whatever reason breaks this specific test.

At first I thought, ok I just need to wait for the browser, this is a system test, but now this wait time has started to creep up to an absurd level. (Side note: a similar thing is happening to a system test for entering a search term into the search bar and waiting for a response.) Is there a better way to test this or telling Capybara to wait for the browser the only way? I know that I can trust Devise and don't need to unit test Devise's password reset mailer, but I would like to test the user's flow through the password reset process.

Here's the flaky test:

```
require 'application_system_test_case'

class UserPasswordResetTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:george)
  end

  test "should allow you to request a password reset email" do
    visit login_path
    click_link "Forgot your password?"
    assert_current_path "/users/password/new"
    using_wait_time(30) do
      fill_in "user[email]", with: @user.email
    end
    click_button "Request password reset"
    using_wait_time(25) do
      assert_text "You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes."
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my test helpers:

[test/application_system_test_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/4200a06c11cc10de7edaa42163c6e32d)

[test/test_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/87c5c005313aa0958b619e2d21445784)

What is a better way to test this password reset flow that isn't as flaky?

Answer (score 1):

If the test is passing with the extended waits, then you need to look at your test log to see why your controller actions are taking so long to render (Capybara is just waiting for that stuff to appear in the browser, and continues as soon as it does). If the tests aren't reliably passing with extended waits then you'll need to provide details on exactly what errors are being returned.

Also note that when you're only adjusting the maximum wait time for a single call you don't need to use the `using_wait_time` method, you can just pass `wait` to the method you're calling

```
fill_in "user[email]", with: @user.email, wait: 30
```

Comment: Thanks. Have never considered tailing my test logs (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tail-your-test-logs) `tail -f log/development.log`. That should help me diagnose the problem.